# How to start bibxy activity using programming?

Tags: android, android-intent, voice-recognition

I am using S8/S8+. I want to call bibxy app from the Intent. However, I cannot call it. How can I call it from Intent?

This is what I try

```
final String SVOICE_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.samsung.voiceserviceplatform";
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setPackage(SVOICE_PACKAGE_NAME);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
getApplication().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

Comment: ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND does not seem right, Samsung might not support it, you probably just need an ACTION_MAIN.

Comment: Thanks, Nikolay Shmyrew. I will check it tomorrow and let you know. DO you know which is correct package name of bibxy in Samsung S8?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```