# What is the Key Constant of the Samsung Bixby Key?

Tags: android, bixby, samsung-galaxy

I want to make an app try to remap what the Bixby key on Samsung Devices do.
But I could not find the Key Constant for the key.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung removed this functionality. But you can use it with Accessibility Service.

See this

[How to receive a Bixby button press event, even if my app is not in front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299480/how-to-receive-a-bixby-button-press-event-even-if-my-app-is-not-in-front)